# webpack configuration in preact-cli

Tags: webpack, preact

I created an app using preact-cli. I want to change some configuration of webpack. I created preact.config.js and passed it to 'preact build' through '--config'. I added this piece of code in preact.config.js to switch off 'hints'.

```
export default function (config, env, helpers) {

    helpers.webpack.performance.hints= "warning"; 

}
```

It is throwing an error: `Cannot set property 'hints' of undefined`.
I expect `performance.hints= "warning"` to be passed on to webpack as a configuration parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the option of modifying the original webpack config directly ([example](https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/wiki/Config-Recipes#setting-proxy-for-dev-server-using-config-directly))

it's passed in via the `config` parameter

this lets us do something like this:

```
if (config.performance) {
    config.performance.hints = false;
}
```

multiple webpack configs are passed through this function

so we check for the `performance` property first as it is only present in certain circumstances ([docs](https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/blob/81c7bb23e9c00ba96da1c4b9caec0350570b8929/src/lib/webpack/webpack-client-config.js#L87))